# Algorithm for stacking events/items

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking to build a pseudo Gantt chart, except one where events can be on the same line as long as they don't overlap, something like this:

```
               M T W R F S U M T W R F S U M T W R F S U
Category 1:   |Event 1|     |Event 2| |------Event 3--|
                |---------Event 4-----------| |-Event 5-|
```

I'm looking for an algorithm to efficiently pack these events.  I know I can use the length of event and the start date to determine overlapping, but I'd like to have some kind of starting point.

For the curious, I'm looking at getting around limitations of the Gantt calendar view in SharePoint 2007.  Our users like that view, but don't want one task per line.

Comment: I can't offer any proof, but my hunch is that finding an optimal solution (which I'd define as a solution with the least possible amount of unscheduled time) is an NP-hard problem. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization

Comment: @erickson: He's not looking to arrange event times to optimize time usage. He just wants to have the events (with known start/end times) appear in as few rows as possible.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - Can you devise an example where the optimal time usage does not yield the fewest number of rows?

Comment: @erickson: My point is that the algorithm he's looking for *cannot* reconfigure the times of the events to optimize time usage. The events will occur when they are set to occur. The algorithm is only choosing which row to place the events in vertically, since their horizontal position is predetermined. Therefore, it is not NP-hard, and the simple greedy algorithm that Jerry posted will find an optimal solution.

Comment: Ah, so he is looking to optimize time usage. It's just not as hard as I thought.

Comment: If "optimize time usage" means trying to find a schedule with the least possible amount of unscheduled time, then no, he's not trying to optimize time usage. If you mean he wants to show a fixed schedule using the fewest possible number of rows, then yes, that's right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first attempt would be to sort the tasks by start time/date. Then I'd place them one at a time on the first line on which their start time wasn't already occupied. I'm not (at all) sure that gives optimal results (i.e., always uses the smallest number of lines possible), but it should at least be halfway reasonable.

The more I think about it, however, the more I think it might actually be optimal. Optimization problems are usually difficult because the number of combinations rises extremely quickly compared to the number of items. In this case, however, you don't really get such a combinatorial explosion because you can't rearrange items -- at least I'm assuming their start times are all pre-set, so they can't be rearranged.

Edit: just to be clear: here I'm assuming that the question deals only with *displaying* a schedule of events for which the start times and durations are already known, so optimization just means displaying the data as "compactly" as possible. I'm *not* talking about attempting to create the schedule itself (i.e., attempting to figure out what events to schedule when). Depending on the constraints involved, that's normally a much more difficult problem. It's fairly easy as long as your only constraints are inter-task dependencies, but when you add things like maximum manpower usage and constrained resources (e.g., task X can only be carried out by person A, B, or C, task Y by B, C or D, etc.), the situation becomes *much* more difficult very quickly.

Comment: Yep, I think that's optimal. For illustration, let c(t) be the number of events that are "active" at a given time t. Then the maximum of c(t) (for all t) will be the minimum number of lines needed for this kind of display. On the other hand, with the kind of "sweep line" algorithm outlined in this answer, I think we can assure that we will always use exactly c(t) lines (for any t).

Comment: We studied this problem in a computer science class, and determined that this greedy algorithm is optimal. I used it in a room scheduling product, and it has worked great for us.

Comment: wow.  i was intending to go with this algorithm, I just hadn't considered that it might already be optimal.  thanks Jerry!